# Textview doesn't show up on the right fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I've implemented avslide function in my app that shows an arrow which tells you which way you can slide. I've 5 fragments one can slide between, and I don't want a left arrow on the first fragment nor do I want a right arrow on the last fragment. However, the left arrow appears on the first fragment but disappears on the second one, and for some reason it adds 6 fragments even though I only need 5. My theory is that it thinks the second fragment is the first somehow. I've commented in the code where I handle the arrows.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
@Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            if(event2.getX() < event1.getX()){
                if(currentFragment == 0){ //I HANDLE THE ARROWS HERE
                    leftarrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else if (currentFragment ==4){
                    rightarrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                if(currentFragment == 0) {
                    removeFragment();
                    Bottomsection1 bottom1 = new Bottomsection1();
                    addDynamicFragment(bottom1);
                    currentFragment = 1;
                }else if(currentFragment ==1) {
                    removeFragment();
                    Bottomsection2 bottom2 = new Bottomsection2();
                    addDynamicFragment(bottom2);
                    currentFragment = 2;
                }else if(currentFragment ==2) {
                    removeFragment();
                    Bottomsection3 bottom3 = new Bottomsection3();
                    addDynamicFragment(bottom3);
                    currentFragment = 3;
                }else if(currentFragment ==3) {
                    removeFragment();
                    Bottomsection4 bottom4 = new Bottomsection4();
                    addDynamicFragment(bottom4);
                    currentFragment = 4;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(event2.getX() > event1.getX()) {
                    if(currentFragment==1) {
                        removeFragment();
                        Bottomsection bottom = new Bottomsection();
                        addDynamicFragment(bottom);
                        currentFragment = 0;
                    } else if(currentFragment==2) {
                        removeFragment();
                        Bottomsection1 bottom1 = new Bottomsection1();
                        addDynamicFragment(bottom1);
                        currentFragment = 1;
                    }else if(currentFragment==3) {
                        removeFragment();
                        Bottomsection2 bottom2 = new Bottomsection2();
                        addDynamicFragment(bottom2);
                        currentFragment = 2;
                    }else if(currentFragment==4) {
                        removeFragment();
                        Bottomsection3 bottom3 = new Bottomsection3();
                        addDynamicFragment(bottom3);
                        currentFragment = 3;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

This is the addDynamicFragment:

```
 private void addDynamicFragment(Fragment bottomsection) {
        FragmentManager FRAGMENTMANAGER=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FRAGMENTTRANSACTION = FRAGMENTMANAGER.beginTransaction();

        activeCenterFragments.add(bottomsection);

        FRAGMENTTRANSACTION.add(R.id.Buttons, bottomsection);
        FRAGMENTTRANSACTION.commit();
    }
```

This is the removeFragment method:

```
 private void removeFragment()
    {
        FragmentManager FRAGMENTMANAGER=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FRAGMENTTRANSACTION = FRAGMENTMANAGER.beginTransaction();

        if (activeCenterFragments.size() > 0) {
            FRAGMENTTRANSACTION = FRAGMENTMANAGER.beginTransaction();
            for (Fragment activeFragment : activeCenterFragments) {
                FRAGMENTTRANSACTION.remove(activeFragment);
            }
            activeCenterFragments.clear();
            FRAGMENTTRANSACTION.commit();
        }
```

Comment: can you include your addDynamicFragment method?

Comment: Yes sure, have edited the OP

Comment: What does your removeFragment() method look like?

Comment: Haved edited the OP, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your arrow conditions and moved them out of their respective if statements. This should fix the arrow problem.

```
    Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if(currentFragment == 0){ //I HANDLE THE ARROWS HERE
                leftarrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                rightarrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (currentFragment ==4){
                rightarrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                leftarrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                rightarrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                leftarrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        if(event2.getX() < event1.getX()){


            if(currentFragment == 0) {
                removeFragment();
                Bottomsection1 bottom1 = new Bottomsection1();
                addDynamicFragment(bottom1);
                currentFragment = 1;
            }else if(currentFragment ==1) {
                removeFragment();
                Bottomsection2 bottom2 = new Bottomsection2();
                addDynamicFragment(bottom2);
                currentFragment = 2;
            }else if(currentFragment ==2) {
                removeFragment();
                Bottomsection3 bottom3 = new Bottomsection3();
                addDynamicFragment(bottom3);
                currentFragment = 3;
            }else if(currentFragment ==3) {
                removeFragment();
                Bottomsection4 bottom4 = new Bottomsection4();
                addDynamicFragment(bottom4);
                currentFragment = 4;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(event2.getX() > event1.getX()) {

                if(currentFragment==1) {
                    removeFragment();
                    Bottomsection bottom = new Bottomsection();
                    addDynamicFragment(bottom);
                    currentFragment = 0;
                } else if(currentFragment==2) {
                    removeFragment();
                    Bottomsection1 bottom1 = new Bottomsection1();
                    addDynamicFragment(bottom1);
                    currentFragment = 1;
                }else if(currentFragment==3) {
                    removeFragment();
                    Bottomsection2 bottom2 = new Bottomsection2();
                    addDynamicFragment(bottom2);
                    currentFragment = 2;
                }else if(currentFragment==4) {
                    removeFragment();
                    Bottomsection3 bottom3 = new Bottomsection3();
                    addDynamicFragment(bottom3);
                    currentFragment = 3;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It still somehow thinks that the second fragment is the first, and it still add 6 fragments cause I've to slide to the right on the 5. fragment to let the rightarrow disappear.